# Blender Eevee shaders look 2D

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

I have recently switched from blender 2.79 to blender 2.8 and i am witnessing some problems with eevee. The shaders in rendered view almost look 2D. When I look at my mesh in material view, i can see all the details on it, such as lighting, shadows, and I can overall tell that it is a 3D mesh. But when I render it, My mesh looks almost 2D, All you can see is color, there is no value, shadows, or lighting to it what so ever. Is there anyway to fix this?

Material view:
[image]

Rendered view:
[image]

Comment: Looks like your world background color is white, try to set it to dark grey

Comment: still looks the same when i change the background color

Comment: In your images it doesn't show the Shadows panel, can you expand that and attach an image?